# Django Migration Errors 1064

Tags: mysql, django, migration

Hey guys I am trying to migrate my data in django using python manage.py migrate command but I keep getting this error and I do not know what could be the problem mind you am new in django

I have tried to drop the database then made the database again in Mariadb and made the migrations again using python manage.py make migrations and then tried to migrate again using python manage.py migrate and I keep getting the same error.

I try to migrate it using:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This is the error I get:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'b'30') NOT NULL, `help_text`
>   longtext NULL, `data_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `' at line 1")

This is the migration that is bringing the problem when I migrate:

```
Applying helpdesk.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c`o`rresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'30') NOT NULL, `help_text` longtext NULL, `data_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `' at line 1")
```

Comment: add your model and migration file

Comment: We would need to see migration file that it's breaking on.

Comment: shafik I have added it above from the edited version